# data is not getting deleted from database

Tags: c#, .net

In windows desktop application form I am using this code for deleting data from datagridview and database ,I have taken one checkbox column in dataridview ,If I click on `checkbox` row is getting deleted at that moment from datagridview ,but not from the database therefore when i reload form i can see that row again ,where I am going wrong?

```
public partial class EditEngClgList : Form
    {        
        private OleDbConnection acccon = null;
        private OleDbDataAdapter da = null;
        private DataTable dt = null;
        private BindingSource bs = null;
        private OleDbCommandBuilder cmdb = null;


        public EditEngClgList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                acccon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db1.mdb");
                acccon.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error:" + err);
            }
            string sql = "Select * From EngColeges order by EngClgID";
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, acccon);
            cmdb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);

            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dt;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Engineering College Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Adress";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Entrance Type";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 400;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<int> checkedclg = new List<int>();
            DataRow dr;
            List<int> checkedclgid = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Delete"].Value) == true)
                {
                    checkedclg.Add(i);
                    checkedclgid.Add(Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Delete"].Value)); 
                }
            }
            foreach (int k in checkedclg)
            {
                dr = dt.Rows[k];               
                dt.Rows[k].Delete();
                foreach (int j in checkedclgid)
                {
                    OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM EngColeges WHERE EngClgID = @clgID", acccon);
                    oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@clgID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = j;
                    oleDbCommand.Prepare();
                    oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure in event `button4_Click` your `foreach` loop runs ? Do you have something in `checkedclg` and `checkedclgid` ? YOu might need to call `dataGridView1.EndEdit();` in event `button4_Click`.

Comment: yes I am getting `row ID` in `checkedclgid`, what purpose `EndEdit` is used for

Comment: If gridView is in editing mode it ends up editing and commit any change made to gridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change this line:

```
checkedclgid.Add(Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Delete"].Value));
```

to the following:

```
checkedclgid.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CellInTheInvisible‌​Column"].Value));
```

Because you're converted a boolean type to Int16 and then you're used it in your query for checking with ID in your related table.

```
OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM EngColeges WHERE EngClgID = @clgID", acccon);
```

So, you must store ID of rows that you want to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Delete"].Value) == true)
{
    checkedclg.Add(i);
    checkedclgid.Add(Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Delete"].Value));
}
```

Looks like the wrong cell value is being passed to `Convert.ToInt16`? It's using the "Deleted" column instead of your ID column.

Also you can delete all the rows in one sql statement using the `where in` clause, for example:
`DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)`

Comment: so what should i pass than? and I don't want to delete all rows ,I just want to delete selected rows

Comment: Pass it the `EngClgID` column. `Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["EngClgID"].Value)` As for only deleting the selected rows, what I mean is construct your SQL query to only have the IDs of the rows you wish to delete. `string.Format("DELETE FROM EngColeges WHERE EngClgID in ({0})", string.Join(",", checkedclgid))` sort of thing.

Comment: If I pass `EngClgID` than how it will check whether checkbox selected or not,because that I can do only by passing Delete column header

Answer (score 1):

Insted of storing value of `Delete` like this

```
checkedclgid.Add(Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Delete"].Value));
```

storing The values of `primary key column` like this deletes data properly from database Also

```
checkedclgid.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["EngClgID"].Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you are deleting the row and then you are attempting to delete it from database. First of all you delete the row from database and then again call the select query for that table.

Answer (score 0):

All you have right now is a `command`. You need your `OleDbDataAdapter`, and pass the `command` to it:

```
...
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, acccon);
da.DeleteCommand = oleDbCommand;
```

More Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.deletecommand.aspx

Comment: This is just an example. Use the DataAdapter from the select (EditEngClgList) also in the delete, or use a global connection. And then pass the DeleteCommand to the DataAdapter like in the link I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace these two lines:

```
oleDbCommand.Prepare();
oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

With:

```
da.DeleteCommand = oleDbCommand;
```

References:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.deletecommand.aspx

Comment: Using your codes, try running your executable in C:\[Project Path]\bin\Debug because Visual Studio might overwrite your updated database with the old database if you have set your database's "copy to output" property to "copy always"